# Twitter bookmarklet is unavailable

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, sharing, twitter, bookmarklet

Due to Buffer.com browser extension not allowing you to unshorten links when sharing on Twitter (they use their own shortener buff.ly unless you purchase a paid plan: https://faq.buffer.com/article/396-publish-unshorten-link ) I was searching for a replacement. I found something similar: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/share-on-twitter/gkjgmeeoldebbdoehhngapnlfmdbmiie?hl=en but I’m not really trusting it.

Then I came across this article https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-revolutionary-bookmarklets-for-sharing-to-replace-your-extensions/ which reminded me of the good old days when I was indeed using such “javascript-bookmarks” aka bookmarklets in Firefox (although I’ve switched to Chrome since then).
Apart from Facebook whose bookmarklet page is still alive https://www.facebook.com/share_options.php, all other services have either put their down or moved to browser extensions.

After a few searches, I finally found Twitter’s own “official” bookmarklet, see announcement here: https://blog.twitter.com/official/en_us/a/2010/tweet-button-bookmarklet-share-links-from-any-page.html (back in 2010!!)
Unfortunately this URL is 404 now: https://developer.twitter.com/pages/share_bookmarklet

Also tried the bookmarklet from here: http://marklets.com/Twitter%20%27Share%27%20Bookmarklet.aspx but this doesn’t seem to even work anymore in Chrome, I can’t drag&drop it to the bookmark bar!!! :(

As said in an answer on SO: “Bookmarklets were sacrificed on the altar of supposed security benefits.”
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505367/why-bookmarklet-does-not-worrk-on-twitter

So how can I find a *good* way to share a link (my current browser tab/page) on Twitter by a single click?

PS: found a somehow related question here [Shortening an URL and Sharing it on Twitter with a Keyboard Shortcut on Firefox/Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/811691/shortening-an-url-and-sharing-it-on-twitter-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-on-firefox) but it was closed in 2014 as “off-topic” (?)

Comment: You are looking for a browser extension that auto-shortens URLs to share on twitter? This is considerably Off-Topic and impractical for browser usage. I recommend `Ctrl` + `C`, `Ctrl` + `V`

Comment: Perhaps a better approach to getting an answer is to broaden your target product. Instead of asking for a URL-shortener specifically for twitter, I'd ask for something like "_auto-shorten-and-copy-to-clipboard_" or "auto-shorten for easy _sharing_." Or take up programming and use SO to help write such an extension.

Comment: @DaMaxContent no I'm not looking for an URL shortener, but a browser-shortcut à la bookmarklet or just a good extension to share a link, the same way I can share a link on Facebook using this extension (which is now unfortunately removed from the Chrome Web Store): https://cws.addtochrome.com/detail/kbgplcfihfeioiaddclapccnefggiddn

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Bookmarklets are no longer on-topic on Web Applications.